# "*Line 1, Column 11 Missing '}' or object member name" Minecraft: Bedrock Edition

Tags: json, minecraft, xbox-one

I was trying to use JSON commands in Minecraft: Xbox One Edition and entered this code below and got "*Line 1, Column 11 Missing '}' or object member name.
`/give @p stick 1 0 {"ench":[{"id":19,"lvl":1000}]}`

Answer (score 0):

This command doesn't work for **minecraft bedrock edition** it only works for **minecraft java edition**.

Because **minecraft bedrock edition** doesn't support NBT editing with commands.

Only **minecraft java edition** does.
[Click this link for information about nbt editing](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/NBT_format)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).